# postgresql create function

Tags: postgresql, function

What is wrong with this function. It gives the error "syntax error at return"

```
create function total (number1 integer, number2 integer, number3 integer) 
returns integer as $$
begin
    return number1 + number2 + number3;
end
$$
language sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change language:

```
create function total (number1 integer, number2 integer, number3 integer) 
returns integer as
$$
begin
    return number1 + number2 + number3;
end;
$$
language plpgsql  --here
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0bba33e36fbd281965dae4e45afb87b0)**

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PL/pgSQL syntax with SQL syntax. A SQL function does not have a `return` part, use `select` instead and remove the `begin ... end` block:

```
create function total (number1 integer, number2 integer, number3 integer) 
  returns integer 
as 
$$
    select number1 + number2 + number3;
$$
language sql;
```

For simple expressions like that a SQL function is more efficient than a PL/pgSQL function.